# How to store filenames with spaces in a variable and pass them to commands in a bash script?

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I'm having trouble handling filenames with spaces in a bash script.

using:

```sh
cat hello\ message\ \(1\).txt
```

successfully prints the file contents.

using:

```sh
file=hello\ message\ \(1\).txt
cat $file
```

returns:

```sh
cat: hello: No such file or directory
cat: message: No such file or directory
cat: '(1).txt': No such file or directory
```

how can i store filenames with spaces in a variable and pass them to commands?

Comment: Use quotes. `cat "$file"`

Answer (score 0):

The variable has the correct value, it's the expansion that's failing. Rule of thumb: always quote variable expansions.

```
cat "$file"
```

Unquoted variable expansions are subject to [glob expansion and word splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it). Think of it as if there were a hidden `split_glob()` function called whenever you omit quotes. `*`, `?`, and other globs are expanded, and spaces are interpreted as word separators.